# How to exclude delimiter in fscanf

Tags: c, file, delimiter, scanf

My file is a text file abcdef;qwerty\n. When I run this program I get

```
abcedef
;qwerty
```

How can I get rid of the semicolon so I would be printing

```
abcedf
qwerty
```

Program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char str1[2000], str2[2000];
    char c; 
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("File not read,errno = %d\n",errno);
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%[^;] %[^\n]",str1,str2);

    printf("%s\n%s\n",str1,str2);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%[^;]%*c%[^\n]",str1,str2);`

Comment: It might be easier to read one line at a time (using e.g. `fgets`) and then split the input on the separator using `strtok`.

Comment: You can get a human readable error message with `fprintf(stderr, "%s: can't open %s: %s\n", argv[0], argv[1], strerror(errno));`